# Virtual Box bridged network and port forwarding VAGRANT

Tags: port-forwarding, bridge, vagrant

Hey guys i'm having serious problme with to portforward my port 5060 i'm stuck on it since 1 week :(
the probleme is i want to portforward the port 5060 on my bridge network not in nat so naturaly i did this

```
  config.vm.network "public_network", :bridge => "Realtek PCIe 2.5GbE Family Controller", :ip => "192.168.1.117"
```

#####DEFAULT ROUTER

```
config.vm.provision "shell",
run: "always",
inline: "route add default gw 192.168.1.254"

config.vm.provision "shell",
run: "always",
inline: "eval `route -n | awk '{ if ($8 ==\"eth0\" && $2 != \"0.0.0.0\") print \"route del default gw \" $2; }'`"
```

config.vm.network "forwarded_port", :adapter=>2, guest: 5060,host: 5060, protocol: "udp"

Then when i do vagrant reload i have this

```
    default: VirtualBox adapter #2 not configured as "NAT". Skipping port
```

in my router i did port forwarding like this 192.168.1.117 / UDP / ALL IP / 5060 / 5060 
and still when i try to check open port through internet its says the port is close